# Book of Illustration of Hindu Gods

Tags: book-recommendation

Any Book or website with best illustration of Hindu Gods.. preferably illustrations based on Dhyan Shloka..

[image: Saraswati] [image: Krishna] [image]

While searching for Book I came across these images.. they seems to be image of pages from an old book. Anyone know this Book.. Image Links [Saraswati](https://tr.pinterest.com/pin/699254279615834029/) [Krishna](https://www.pinterest.com.au/pin/597078863071808969/) [Indra](https://www.pinterest.es/pin/774056254685579148/)

Comment: @Rickross I thought you would know..^^

Comment: probably from Kalyan magazine from Gitapress Gorakhpur http://book.gitapress.org/product-category/topic/annual-number-of-kalyan/

Comment: @Ketan Thanks..and Do You know any Book with best illustration of Hindu Gods.. preferably based on Dhyan Shloka..

Comment: You want books comprised of only images of gods? Or you want books comprised of Dhyana Slokas of various deities? I have few books that have both but those are in Bengali. The book "Nitya Karma Puja Prakash" has images of the 5 main deities. @HinduKid But once you know the Dhyana Sloka you already know the appearance of a deity.

Comment: @Rickross Books comprised of images of gods.. coloured,, preferably **based on** Dhyan Shloka.. Like the Kalyan Magazine book pics I posted.. I came to know that, they are pics from Kalyan Magazine, but couldnt find Which Month, which Years Edition

Comment: @HinduKid The images contained in ur Q are definitely from books published by the Gita Press. In [this](https://ia802504.us.archive.org/34/items/HindiBookNityaKarmPoojaPrakashCompletebyGitaPress/Hindi%20Book-Nitya-Karm-Pooja-Prakash(Complete)by%20Gita%20Press.pdf) book from pp 15 onwards u'll find similar images of various deities. All drawn by some B.K.Mitra. However those are not colored. Also, no one can be sure if those images are correctly drawn as per respective Dhyana Slokas unless one sees the Slokas.

Comment: @Rickross Im thankful for you.. For searching this book...  and the images doesnt have to be based on dhyan shloka... dhyan shloka was just my preference...Im searching for Book with Images of God..