# Which one is more effective, after prayer requesting to god in Sanskrit vs in English?

Tags: mantras, sanskrit

Sanskrit is Language of Gods..
So say that, after I chant below mantra in mind..

**वक्रतुण्ड महाकाय सूर्यकोटि समप्रभ ।**

**निर्विघ्नं कुरु मे देव सर्वकार्येषु सर्वदा ॥**

after chanting mantra in mind, Now I make some request to God, should I make those requests in Sanskrit, would it be more effective to make the request in Sanskrit..

As My request

Should I say **I want to become intelligent**..<-- request in English

OR **मैं बुद्धिमान बनना चाहता हूं** <-- request in Sanskrit

Which one is more effective.. is request made in Sanskrit more effective than request made in English, since Sanskrit is language of God

Comment: @YDS..No.. The language of Mantra isnt changed..In this question >> the language, using which you make your request to the God; is changed.

Comment: @YDS .When you pray to the god, you make some request to the God within your mind.. Im asking if making request in Sanskrit is better than making request in English..Instead of requesting in my mind in English-**Lord Ganesha Please Remove Obstacles from My Life**- Is it better to request in Sanskrit-**भगवान गणेश मेरे जीवन की बाधाओं को दूर करें**-

Comment: "Is it better to request in Sanskrit-भगवान गणेश मेरे जीवन की बाधाओं को दूर करें"-- It's Hindi language and not Sanskrit...and it's somewhat rough Hindi translation of 2nd line of Sanskrit mantra.

Comment: @YDS. Oh..Please tell me the Sanskrit translation for **Lord Ganesha Please Remove Obstacles from My Life** ..

Comment: @YDS.. "and it's somewhat rough Hindi translation of 2nd line of Sanskrit mantra."... **The Language in which Mantra is chanted isnt changed**.. but after chanting Mantra, or Praying for God, you make some requests to the God.. **The language in which you make your requests in changed**..

Comment: the mantra is in Sanskrit only... "निर्विघ्नं कुरु मे देव सर्वकार्येषु सर्वदा" is only translated in "Lord Ganesha Please Remove Obstacles from My Life"...so if u chant the mantra, there is no need at all to utter it's Hindi/English translation...mantra itself contain both the prayer and request...

Comment: @YDS.. I have edit the Question.. The point is that, The Prayer/Mantra your chanting and request your making has no correlation..

Comment: The best and most sincere method is to pray from your heart, for there are people who can not speak but even their prayers are accepted by the Almighty !

Comment: Faith is more important, language is secondary. If sanskrit was necessary for communicating with God or deities, there wont have been so many scriptures in several languages.

Comment: You can pray to god in your mother tongue. If that is English then that will be fine. When it's technical like reciting Stotras and Mantras then it has to be done in the language they are originally in i.e. in Sanskrit. @HinduKid

Comment: @Rickross .. Understood .. Mother tongue is Konkani.. any thing about this [Q](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/38089/book-of-illustration-of-hindu-gods)

Comment: God is not kattarpanthi who will say that If you will pray in my language, only then I will listen. If you wanna do prayer then learn Sanskrit first then talk to me, not before that... Nope, He will accept your prayer in any language because God's love towards us is not dependent on any language.